# Unresolved application library references, defined in weblogic-application.xml

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf

I am running an application in JDeveloper version 12.2.1.4 when i run the application on defalut local weblogic it will gives me a below error.

```
<Jul 5, 2022 2:55:41,487 PM PKT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1619203909972800" for task "5" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.management.DeploymentException: [J2EE:160149]Error while processing library references. Unresolved application library references, defined in weblogic-application.xml: [Extension-Name: sharelib, exact-match: false]"
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: [J2EE:160149]Error while processing library references. Unresolved application library references, defined in weblogic-application.xml: [Extension-Name: sharelib, exact-match: false]
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.CheckLibraryReferenceFlow.prepare(CheckLibraryReferenceFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:241)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:66)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your weblogic-application.xml you have defined a library reference named 'shareLib'.

This library needs to be installed on your Weblogic server.
The error tells you hat this library is not installed on your server.